# PHP Facebook API using user credentials to bypass login prompt

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the [facebook api](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) to post data. Currently, the user has to login every time they want to post from my application. I'd like to know if there is any way I can retrieve a token of some sort from facebook (and save it to the database) to connect the user and bypass the user login. Here's the code I have so far:

```
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages';
$config=array(
    'appId'=>self::FB_APPID,
    'secret'=>self::FB_SECRET
);
$this->_facebook = new Facebook($config);
$fbUser=$this->_facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: I just want to make sure if I understood correctly. Do you actually want some sort of "keep me logged in"? And if so, based on user's IP or on user's facebook account, so when the user logs in its account, he would automatically log in to your app?

Comment: I want to be able to just have the user type a post in a textarea and then post it (on my application), without having to have the user go through the login process into facebook.

Comment: Im not quite following what you are saying, but I think my prior comment is pretty clear as to what Id like to accomplish.

Comment: From my experience (not very much, but anyway..), this should happen automatically, unless the user logs out. A change in your app's state should not require a new login, simply because the user is still logged on fb.

Comment: I dont want to be dependent on if the user is logged in or out. I want to know if theres a way I can do facebook posts using the facebook SDK without the user having to be logged in (as i mentioned, using a token of some sort).

Comment: This is only possible WITH the user's prior consent, but I haven't done this so far. What I know is that you need an access_token from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the main function:

```
$bpath=realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once $bpath.'/vendors/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages';
$config=array(
    'appId'=>'appid',
    'secret'=>'secret'
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$access_token='someaccesstoken';
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
$params=array('message' => 'testing facebook SDK');
$facebook->api('/me/feed','post',$params);
```

On Login Function:

```
$bpath=realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once $bpath.'/vendors/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages';
$config=array(
    'appId'=>'appid',
    'secret'=>'secret'
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$fbUser=$facebook->getUser();
$accesstoken=$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: Glad if it helped in any way :). Might be useful if you posted some of the code and how to find it for future users